# How to identify which DataFrame a row originated after a merge fro rows flagged as both after indicator=True

Tags: pandas, merge

My issue is that I want to be able know which dataframe a row is source from after a merge, in particular the rows returned for both `indicator=True` = `both`.

```
Left
|   | A | B |
|---|---|---|
| 0 | a | 2 |
| 1 | b | 3 |
| 2 | c | 5 |
| 3 | d | 5 |

Right

|   | A | R |
|---|---|---|
| 0 | a | 3 |
| 1 | b | 4 |
| 2 | e | 7 |
| 3 | f | 5 |

Both = Left.merge(Right,right_on ="A", left_on="A", how ="outer", indicator=True)

Output
|   | A | B   | R   | _merge     |
|---|---|-----|-----|------------|
| 0 | a | 2.0 | 3.0 | both       |
| 1 | b | 3.0 | 4.0 | both       |
| 2 | c | 5.0 | NaN | left_only  |
| 3 | d | 5.0 | NaN | left_only  |
| 4 | e | NaN | 7.0 | right_only |
| 5 | f | NaN | 5.0 | right_only |
```

I want to figure out a way to identify the source dataframe from the rows that have `_merge` = "both"

I have performed an outer merge as I need all combinations as a data source for Tableau, so I can perform basic stats on original DataFrames as separate entities as well as the merged.

This is a one-to-many relationship between the 2 DataFrames.

How can I decipher what DataFrame a row belongs to when a one-to-may relationship exists?

Comment: If the indicator is "both" then both inputs are used in the row... What you expect is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to preserve the left index after merging. You can reset index of left dataframe before that:

```
Both = Left.reset_index().merge(Right,right_on ="A", left_on="A", how ="outer", indicator=True)
print(Both)

# Output
   index  A    B    R      _merge
0    0.0  a  2.0  3.0        both
1    1.0  b  3.0  4.0        both
2    2.0  c  5.0  NaN   left_only
3    3.0  d  5.0  NaN   left_only
4    NaN  e  NaN  7.0  right_only
5    NaN  f  NaN  5.0  right_only
```

Now, index can be extract with:

```
idx = Both.loc[Both['_merge'] == 'both', 'index'].astype(Left.index.dtype).tolist()

BothLeft = Left.loc[idx]
print(BothLeft)

# Output
   A  B
0  a  2
1  b  3
```

---

**Alternative**

Without merging, you can also check if rows are both in the two dataframes:

```
# For one column to check (Series)
m = Left['A'].isin(Right['A'])
print(Left[m])

# For multiple columns to check (DataFrame) -> need to aggregate along column axis
# m = Left[['A', 'B']].isin(Left[['A', 'B']]).all(axis=1)

# Output
   A  B
0  a  2
1  b  3
```

Note: you must have the same column names for both dataframes.